# In landscape-sysinfo change cpu temp from celsius to fahrenheit

Tags: temperature, landscape

I would like for Landscape-sysinfo to display the cpu temp's in Fahrenheit instead of Celsius. Does anyone know how to accomplish this? I assume that the temperature reading is coming from /lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/sysinfo/temperature.py. Below is the contents of that file. Thanks in advance for your help.

from twisted.internet.defer import succeed

from landscape.lib.sysstats import get_thermal_zones

class Temperature(object):

```
def __init__(self, thermal_zone_path=None):
    self._thermal_zone_path = thermal_zone_path

def register(self, sysinfo):
    self._sysinfo = sysinfo

def run(self):
    temperature = None
    max_value = None
    for zone in get_thermal_zones(self._thermal_zone_path):
        if (zone.temperature_value is not None and
            (max_value is None or zone.temperature_value > max_value)
            ):

            temperature = zone.temperature
            max_value = zone.temperature_value
    if temperature is not None:
        self._sysinfo.add_header("Temperature", temperature)
    return succeed(None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the code example in this post. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1516573

On Ubuntu 22.04 the file location was here:

```
sudo nano /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/sysinfo/temperature.py
```